# Is it possible to specify a round icon for Pixel devices in a Progressive Web App?

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Google's Pixel devices use round icons on their home screens, even for third party apps, as long as that third party app specifies the location of a round icon file.

Is there a way to achieve this same functionality in a Progressive Web App's manifest.json?

I skimmed through Google's documentation, but couldn't find anything. I'm hoping there may be an undocumented method to achieve this.

- https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1.html#circular-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Check the example given in this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/migrate-to-progressive-web-apps/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2) from the Google Developers site; I just tested that example on my pixel and it places a round icon on the homescreen.